# "Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions" - gives error - "The distributor has not been installed correctly"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to replication.  I have two sql server 2008 servers running on windows 2008 R2.  The servers are in two different locations and on two different domains.  I have been able to use aliases to get both "Snapshot publication" and "Transactional Publication" working perfectly.  But what I need is "Transactional publication with updatable subscriptions" so if a change is made on either server, the changes are replicated to the other server.

When I run through the New Publication, I get through every page to the very end with no problem but when I click the finish button I get an error.  There are three actions and it fails on the first action called "Creating Publication 'xxxx'"  The message I get is "SQL Server could not create publication 'xxxx'.  an exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.  The distributor has not been installed correctly."

I have searched for an answer and cannot find it.  I think this is a permission problem between the two servers but I have no idea how to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the installation of different types of replication over the top of one that was previously implemented can cause issues.

If able I would suggest clearing all replication and starting from scratch with your new approach.

You have to run a variety of stored procedures to get it completely off the server.  Using the GUI only doesn't do nearly as good a job of cleaning everything off.

This guide from Microsoft should get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152757.aspx